# No App works on Arc Welder Google Chrome app

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

[image: erro faced]

I downloaded this chrome extension, about 2 months ago any app would work on this, but then today i reinstalled this and no app works, no matter how small or big the android app is, i'd get the same error screen. 
Any Idea?

Comment: Please [file a bug](http://goo.gl/megdlG), and include the messages you see in the console log for Arc Welder. You can see the messages by navigating to chrome://inspect/#apps and clicking the inspect link for that app while the app is running (after the crash).